# How does PeerBlock generate range descriptions?

Tags: firewalls, tcp

How does [PeerBlock](http://forums.peerblock.com/) generate the range that it displays? I thought it was through some DNS lookup, but [when I do the lookup](http://www.tcpiputils.com/browse/ip-address/89.255.249.1) I get LeaseWeb Content Delivery Network for the attached screenshot. Instead PeerBlock is telling me it's coming from a Russian Telecoms provider.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## It's in the list file itself

Peer Block works off of IP lists that you download and enable to block IP addresses on the list unless you allow them. This list also contains meta information in a format such as Label:XXX.XXX.XXX. They're really just .txt files generated by communities after they find someone you shouldn't connect too.

Taken directly from a list file:

```
China Internet Information Center (CNNIC):1.2.4.0-1.2.4.255
China Internet Information Center (CNNIC):1.2.8.0-1.2.8.255
Botnet on Telekom Malaysia:1.9.96.105-1.9.96.105
Botnet on Telekom Malaysia:1.9.102.251-1.9.102.251
Botnet on Telekom Malaysia:1.9.106.186-1.9.106.186
```

As you can see the entries contain those labels you see as well as ranges, and when PeerBlock blocks one of the IPs it displays the label information in the log.